# Compare two lists, without Compare-Object

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have two lists saved in variables `$list1` and `$list2`.
Now I want to compare them. Somehow, `Compare-Object` is giving me the wrong output, even though the user is in both lists it still says

> not equal

Comment: Please update your question with examples of your lists and the specific Compare-Object command you are using

Comment: Okay forget it, I had a mistake in my code so it only outputs me 1 name in $list1

Comment: Can you plz share the sample data in both the lists..

Comment: @seyo-IV I'm confused by your comment, is your issue solved? Can you update your question to review any changes? Can you provide your own answer? This really helps SO provide the best references as possible for future visitors :)